# There is a jquery or javascript plugin for templating pages like facelets or tiles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, facelets, apache-tiles

There is a jquery or javascript plugin for templating pages like facelets or tiles, for example:

template.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <insert id="content" />
   </body>
</html>
```

content1.html

```
<html>
    <composition src="template.html">
        <define>
            My frist content
        </define>
    </composition>
</html>
```

content2.html

```
<html>
    <composition src="template.html">
        <define>
            My second content
        </define>
    </composition>
</html>
```

any idea?

I need make this only with javascript or jquery!

My app is only html and jquery, nothing jsf. So, I need a jquery plugin for make this. This html is only an example.

Comment: I need make this only with javascript or jquery!

Comment: I afraid that you can't include another JSF component with javascript or jQuery

Comment: My app is only html and jquery, nothing jsf. So, I need a jquery plugin for make this. This html is only an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain html, meaning no jsp, php old fashioned cgi-bin or whatever (including jquery, since I personally do not consoder this plain html ;-) ), I was almost 1000% sure there is no solution.

But after a little searching in google it looks like things are possible with html5. Just search in google for 'html(5) templating'

E.g. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

And as mentioned in the comment to this answer, lots of jquery plugins can be found using google.

Comment: He use plain html, he wrote it in comments to question.  Btw, I've found a lot jQuery plugins for templating by google, don't know are they are simple as JSF templating but I think that it's possible.

Comment: That !s why I corrected my answer afterwards after a little searching. I **assumed** (and obviously wrongfully so) that he did some basic searching in google as well. If you can find jquery plugins (I did not search for jquery since it is also not plain html ;-) )and I found an html5 way, why didn't he find those. But I corrected my answer. Most likely others will do the searching as well and copy/paste something here. Those are the answers SO wants but Ihave a different opinion.